# XPath function to combine text nodes and retrieve it to one Google Spreadsheet cell

Tags: xpath

I'm completely rookie in XPath (I don't even know how to paste proper html into this post ;-p) subject and I need some help. I would like to retrieve text which is in quotation marks and put it into a one cell in Google Spreadsheet. Right now I can only retrieve this text into separate cells.

http://imm.io/oLYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `string(//tr[class='darkGreen']/td[2])` result in what you want? Your XML fragment looks incomplete and I'm not sure if you only want the contents of the second cell so it's a wild guess if this fits your need.

Comment: It doesn't work in this example (it returns only the first text node), but maybe first you can tell is it possible to do so? I mean - combine few text nodes and put this combined text into one cell in spreadsheet?

Comment: After few modifications it finally works. Sorry for the mix-up and thank you very much :-)